# How to add a delete and edit function into my HTML table which is filled with info from my MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've made this simple PHP/HTML table which shows info in my database, now i want to add a delete and edit function using the SQL DELETE and EDIT functions.

How can i implent this so that every row has a delete button and edit button automaticly when its added to the DB?

**Table**

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">CI nummer</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Aankoopdatum</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Serienummer</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Merk</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Model</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">OS</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Eigenaar</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Locatie</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Bewerken</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Verwijderen</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teradruk");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met de database!";
            exit();
        }

        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM `hardware`";

        if ($stmti = $conn->prepare($sqli)) {
            if (!$stmti->execute()) {
                echo "cant exec: <br> " . $stmti->error;
                exit();
            } else {
                $stmti->bind_result($cinummer, $aankoopdatum, $serienummer, $merk, $model, $os, $eigenaar, $locatie, $applicatie);
                $stmti->store_result();

                while($stmti->fetch()) {
                    echo "<tr>
                        <td>$cinummer</td>
                        <td>$aankoopdatum</td>
                        <td>$serienummer</td>
                        <td>$merk</td>
                        <td>$model</td>
                        <td>$os</td>
                        <td>$eigenaar</td>
                        <td>$locatie</td>
                        </tr>";
                }

            }
        } else {
            echo "can't prepare: <br> " . $stmti->error;
            exit();
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: add your while loop in last row ajax click function in pass hardware unique id and call ajax server side add sql delete query where unique id.

Comment: Don't really know how to do that, but I'll try, thx :)

Comment: The SQL edit function?

Comment: Yeah I know about the SQL function @Strawberry , only problem i i dont know how to make it work that every new row/existing row gets a edit + delete button.

Comment: Maybe you know about it, but I've never heard of it before

Comment: Im sorry I see it's called UPDATE not Edit

Answer (score 0):

I just update the code. but I did not create a EDIT form in HTML and send values, I have write PHP codes

```
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">CI nummer</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Aankoopdatum</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Serienummer</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Merk</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Model</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">OS</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Eigenaar</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Locatie</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Bewerken</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Verwijderen</th>
        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Options</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teradruk");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met de database!";
            exit();
        }

        if($_GET['action']=="delete")
        {
            $sql_delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM hardware WHERE PRIMARY_KEY_OF_hardware_TABLE = ".$_GET['id']." ");
        }
        elseif($_GET['action']=="edit")
        {


            $sql_update = "UPDATE hardware SET cinummer = 'New Number' WHERE PRIMARY_KEY_OF_hardware_TABLE = ".$_GET['id']." ";
        }


        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM `hardware`";

        if ($stmti = $conn->prepare($sqli)) {
            if (!$stmti->execute()) {
                echo "cant exec: <br> " . $stmti->error;
                exit();
            } else {
                $stmti->bind_result($cinummer, $aankoopdatum, $serienummer, $merk, $model, $os, $eigenaar, $locatie, $applicatie);
                $stmti->store_result();

                while($stmti->fetch()) {
                    echo "<tr>
                        <td>$cinummer</td>
                        <td>$aankoopdatum</td>
                        <td>$serienummer</td>
                        <td>$merk</td>
                        <td>$model</td>
                        <td>$os</td>
                        <td>$eigenaar</td>
                        <td>$locatie</td>
                        <td><a href='filename.php?id=".$PRIMARY_KEY_OF_hardware_TABLE."&action=delete'>Delete</a> | <a href='filename.php?id=".$PRIMARY_KEY_OF_hardware_TABLE."&action=edit'>Edit</a></td>
                        </tr>";
                }

            }
        } else {
            echo "can't prepare: <br> " . $stmti->error;
            exit();
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much! Looks great! 1 think, im now getting this: http://prntscr.com/d45318 , how can i fix this?..

Comment: Hi, please replace this "PRIMARY_KEY_OF_hardware_TABLE" with your table auto increament primary id.

Comment: Still getting these 2 errors: http://prntscr.com/d45lv2 , when i click delete i get this: http://prntscr.com/d45m1q , sorry for the newbie questions by the way

Comment: I see the problem already, the action function is not regocnized. How do i make this work?